# whats wrong when I use for loop for creating a matirx?

Tags: matrix

When I use separate value for "i" and "j", I got the correct desirable answer.

a = 2;
i = 3;
j = 3;

!(*SubscriptBox[(matrix), ([([a])])]) = {{1, 1, 3}, {7, 4, 
    7}, {2, 6, 8}};
value = Part[matrix[[a]], i, j];
Print [value];
noofbit = IntegerDigits[value, 2]
z = FromDigits [noofbit]
Part[
!(*SubscriptBox[(matrix), ([([a])])]), i, j] = z
Print[
!(*SubscriptBox[(matrix), ([([a])])])]

But when I use "i" and "j" in loop I get error;for what so ever reason...

```
a = 2;
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,

\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(matrix\), \([\([a]\)]\)]\) = {{1, 1, 3}, {7, 4, 
        7}, {2, 6, 8}}
      value = Part[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(matrix\), \([\([a]\)]\)]\), i, j];
   Print [value]
     noofbit = IntegerDigits[value, 2]
      z = FromDigits [noofbit]
       Part[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(matrix\), \([\([a]\)]\)]\), i, j] = z
   ]];
Print[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(matrix\), \([\([a]\)]\)]\)]
```

Can anyone tell me whtas the problem in my code?Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I get errors for both segments of code.  What are you trying to represent with `\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(matrix\), \([\([a]\)]\)]\)`?  Also, note that your expression for `value` is not the same in the two segments of code.

Comment: i just want to run this codeFor[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
   matrix = {{1, 1, 3}, {7, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 8}}
      value = Part[matrix, i, j];
   Print [value]
     noofbit = IntegerDigits[value, 2]
      z = FromDigits [noofbit]
       Part[matrix, i, j] = z
   ]];
Print[matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, this code seems to work:

```
a = 2; matrix = {{1, 1, 3}, {7, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 8}};
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,  For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
         value = Part[matrix, i, j]; Print [value];
         noofbit = IntegerDigits[value, 2];
         z = FromDigits [noofbit]; Part[matrix, i, j] = z]];
Print[matrix]
```

The statements inside the `For` loops must be separated by semicolons.